# javascript Regex: replace two commas with one ,, -> ,

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace two commas with one ,, -> , in javascript.

Cant get I, but this does not work O_o:

```
text.replace(/,,/g, ',')
```

Comment: Your `text.replace(/,,/g, ',')` looks ok to me. How does it _not_ work?

Answer (score 4):

You should either use a string literal:

```
text.replace(',,', ',')
```

Or a regex literal

```
text.replace(/,,/g, ',')
```

Using `'/,,/'` will search for the string `"/,,/"` (slash, comma, comma, slash) and replace it with a comma.

Comment: Sorry shame on my there was more then two commas in string =))

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes:

```
text.replace(/,,/g, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes around the regular expression. Just do this:

```
text.replace(/,,/g, ',')
```

Comment: This *is* using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You know.. replace only returns replaced value, text will be the same text before replacement
You must override this var..

```
text = text.replace(/,,/g, ',');
```